# How do I add a UINaivgationBar to a view that's part of a TabBarController

Tags: c#, .net, ios, xamarin.ios

I'm still getting used to the whole "Controller" flow of iPhone development.

I'm using MonoTouch to build my app.

So my rootController is a TabBarController set in AppDelegate.

```
        tabBarController = new UITabBarController ();
        tabBarController.ViewControllers = new UIViewController [] {
            mapView,
            items,
            account
        };
```

In one of my view's however, I'd like to have a UINavigationControl, so that people can click on items, then have the option to go back.

So here's my constructor for my MapView.

```
    public MapViewController () : base ("MapViewController", null)
    {
        Title = "Map";
        TabBarItem.Image = UIImage.FromBundle ("Images/first");
    }
```

So how do I add other types of ViewControllers at this point?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Instead of using your `MapViewController` in the tab bar, just add a `UINavigationController` instead.
On that you then push the `MapViewController`. If your `MapViewController` pushes then another controller on top of the `UINavigationController`'s stack, the `UINavigationController` will handle the "go back" work for you by providing a button in its top toolbar, a `UINavigationItem`.

You might want to read into the documentation of `UINavigationController` and all the samples around.